# Accessing TextBoxes in WPF DataBound ListBox with foreach

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a databound WPF ListBox with a custom itemtemplate -> datatemplate. Part of that template is also a ListBox.
On certain event I'd like to loop through all textboxes in the ListBox and retreive their values. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by using the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms592860.aspx) and finding elements in the template:

```
foreach (var item in lb.Items)
{
    var itemContainer = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
    // Name the TextBox in the template to find it here.
    var textBox = itemContainer.ContentTemplate.FindName("?????", itemContainer) as TextBox; 
    var value = textBox.Text;
}
```

(*If the TextBoxes you referred to are within the ListBox which is in the template you have to dig deeper by repeating the same method.*)